# How to create JSON in java for pipe delimiter?

Tags: java

Suppose i have this structure

```
FirstName| Auro
LastName|Winkies
Age|26
```

How can we convert it into json I want the word which are before pipe delimiter `|`  should be in `L` property and the word which are after pipe delimiter `|` should be shuffled and saved it into another property `R` and the `C` property is like `Winkies` is at `2 position` after pipe delimiter , similarly `auro` is at `1 position` and `26` is at `3 position`

Is it possible to create this json structure in java.

I thought first i need to split `\n` and further split it into `\\|`

```
{
"L": ["FirstName" , "LastName" ,  "Age"],
"R": ["Winkies" , "Auro" , "26"],
"C":["2" ,"1" , "3"]
}
```

If possible anybody can help me out with the logic

Answer (score 1):

i don't find the utility of the "C" field but here is solution

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.JsonNodeFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    String data = "FirstName|Auro\n" +
                  "LastName|Winkies\n" +
                  "Age|26";

    List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> r = new ArrayList<>();
    ObjectNode node = JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode();
    List<String> c = Arrays.asList("1,2,3");

    String[] split = data.split("\n");
    for (String s : split) {
        int i = s.indexOf('|');
        l.add(s.substring(0, i));
        r.add(s.substring(i + 1, s.length()));
    }
    node.put("L",l.toString());
    node.put("R",r.toString());
    node.put("C",c.toString());

    System.out.println(node);
}
```